# simplexml_load_file problems while browsing securely

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm getting a lot of errors when I browse a clients site securely that have to do with the simplexml_load_file function. Here's an example:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: https://xxxxxxxx/settings.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty in /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/ on line 0`

The site is on a dedicated server from SingleHop. It only happens when I browse the site with `https://`, and works fine when browsed with `http://`.

Seems to be loading the XML file just fine with `https://` as well:
https://consumerstrust.org/wp-content/plugins/easyfanpagedesign/framework/settings.xml

The XML is parsed from a class:

```
public function efpd_load_settings($xmlfile){
    $xmlparse=simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
    $settings=array();
    $setint=0;
    foreach($xmlparse->option as $xml){
        $option[$setint]=(array)$xml;
        array_push($settings,$option[$setint]);
        $setint++;
    }
    return $settings;
}
```

and ran like this:

```
$efpdxml=plugins_url('settings.xml',__FILE__); // plugins_url() is a WP function - returns the value just fine.
$efpdsettings=Efpd::efpd_load_settings($efpdxml);
```

Is this something that happens commonly? Also anything to fix it? If you need any more info to help me solve this just let me know and I will provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to cURL request the file to your server?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the document is empty (as it doesn't have any child nodes). Can you access it in your browser using `https` and confirm that you can see the XML?

Comment: @brady.vitrano - I'm not quite sure how to do that to be honest :( -- @Francois Deschenes - I accessed the XML file using `https` and I see all of the XML just fine, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: If `$efpdxml` returns the correct URL (https://consumerstrust.org/wp-content/plugins/easyfanpagedesign/framework/settings.xml) which can be viewed in a browser, then I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem, but thank you to those of you who tried helping me. I appreciate it.

**My solution:**

This was being run in WordPress, so I really should have posted this in the WPSE site, but I don't blame anyone for not knowing all about WP from this site if they didn't.

The function `plugins_url()` should not have been used to define the path to the XML file, I should have been using `dirname(__FILE__).'/settings.xml'` - which is pretty obvious as to why if you know how `plugins_url()` works, I overlooked it completely but in the end solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) works just fine.

```
    $content = file_get_contents("https://consumerstrust.org/wp-content/plugins/easyfanpagedesign/framework/settings.xml");
    if ( empty($content) ) {
        die('XML is empty');
    }
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
```

**Edit**

Using `simplexml_load_file` with `https` URL also worked for me. This is only an alternative.

Comment: If you go here: https://consumerstrust.org you can see all the errors. And they go away when you go to  http://consumerstrust.org - Very odd to me, I've never encountered a problem like this before.

Comment: Now, I understand your problem. I was thinking you're having a problem loading the XML file when trying to load it using https from a remote server. In order to help, you will need to show the code of how your loading that file.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with some code samples from my application.